# preg_match_all и строка с переменными

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка с формулой `$quant*($c_paper+$c_color)+$quant*$c_lam+$quant*$c_big+$c_cut`
Нужно разобрать её на массив, содержащий имена переменных `c_paper`, `c_color` и т. д.

Делаю так:

```
$string  = '$quant*($c_paper+$c_color)+$quant*$c_lam+$quant*$c_big+$c_cut';
$pattern = "/\$([a-z\_]+)/";
$found = preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Ничего не находит. Я, так понимаю, он интерпретирует строку с формулой как строку, содержащую переменные. как убедить его, что `$` - обычный символ?

Comment: все у вас работает - https://www.regex101.com/r/eA7gD7/2

Comment: в том-то и дело. что на regex101 работает, я им тоже пользуюсь. а в коде пытаюсь дебажить, и результат поиска нулевой.

Comment: Сделайте echo $Pattern, там все видно. Надо так: `$pattern = "/\\\$([a-z\\_]+)/"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо так:

```
$string  = '$quant*($c_paper+$c_color)+$quant*$c_lam+$quant*$c_big+$c_cut';
$pattern = '/\$([a-z\_]+)/';
// или $pattern = "/\\$([a-z\_]+)/";
echo preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches), PHP_EOL;
print_r($matches[1]);
```

[Пример использования](http://ideone.com/yJLESx)

Символ доллара в регулярном выражении нужно либо экранировать дважды (сначала сам знак для движка PHP, потом для движка регулярных выражений), либо использовать одиночные кавычки. Второй способ предпочтительнее, но всё зависит от конкретной ситуации: если необходима интерполяция переменных внутри регулярного выражения, нужны двойные кавычки и двойное экранирование.

Comment: да, я знаю что он возвращает. но возвращает он `0`.

Comment: А Вы ковычки на одиночные поменяйте. `$pattern = '/\$([a-z\_]+)/';`

Comment: хммм. а вот это помогло. и было неожиданностью для меня :)

Comment: Я поправил объяснение. Рад помочь.